# how to get python 3 to accept both integer and string answers

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, integer

I need the code to be able to accept both the integer and string version of 1 and 2. I tried using str() and int() on the input() but it doesn't work and only accepts the integer form of 1 and 2. If the user's input isn't 1, one, 2, or two, i need the game to exit. Any help is appreciated.

```
print ('\n If you want to play the first game, enter 1.')
print ('I you want to play the second game, enter 2.')

gamechoice = str(int(input('\nPlease select the difficulty of the game: '))).lower()
if gamechoice == 1 or 'one':
    Firstgame()
elif gamechoice == 2 or 'two':
    secondgame()
else:
    print ('\nSorry i dont undrstand')
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Better to just treat them both as strings. What is the point of converting them to ints at all?

Comment: your `gamechoice` can never be anything but number in string format ... plus you should catch any exceptions because str(int('one')) would fail big time.

Comment: Experimentation in the Python shell will learn you a lot about this kind of thing.

Answer (score 6):

Based on how you seem to be checking for user input, you are better off not type-casting your input.

First, remove all the type casting you have in your input:

```
gamechoice = input('\nPlease select the difficulty of the game: ')
```

Now, what you will have is most definitely a string no matter what the user entered. At this point what you should do is test to see if `gamechoice` matches the expected values to toggle the appropriate game. You can make use of `in` with your conditional statement like this:

```
if gamechoice.lower() in ('1', 'one'):
     Firstgame()
elif gamechoice.lower() in ('2', 'two'):
     secondgame()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should usually treat user input as a string because you cannot guarantee what they are going to do.  Then you would use something like x.isdigit() before using the int(x) method to convert it to an int.

Comment: python strings do have an `.isdigit()` method. No need to reinvent the wheel.